# Lowest Common Ancestor in a Binary Tree, read the input and algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I'm  trainee and have a problem with that I can't solve this problem alone. So please help me. I found many topics but I could not find a solution.
I just start to learn C# and I'm not sure how to do this. I know that is a simple job but realy I need to understand and solve it. I try to do something but it is only some code. I did my binary tree with some values, have a node class and print method.
Please tell me how to write a code that can read a tree from the Console, because I don't want to have any hardcorde. And then how to find a lowest common ancestor - I see the BFS and DFS algorithms so maybe I can find something, but I'm not sure.
I've read much about this but I can not explain many things. Her
Here is the my code:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var binatyTree = new BinaryTree<int>(1,
                                 new BinaryTree<int>(2,
                                     new BinaryTree<int>(4),
                                      new BinaryTree<int>(5)),
                                  new BinaryTree<int>(3,
                                     new BinaryTree<int>(6,
                                        new BinaryTree<int>(9),
                                        new BinaryTree<int>(10)),
                                     new BinaryTree<int>(7))
                );
            Console.WriteLine("Binary Tree:");
            binatyTree.Print();
        }
    }
```

my binary tree and print method:

```
public class BinaryTree<T>
        {
            public T Value { get; set; }
            public BinaryTree<T> LeftChildren { get; set; }
            public BinaryTree<T> RightChildren { get; set; }
            public BinaryTree(T value, BinaryTree<T> leftChildren = null, BinaryTree<T> rightChildren = null)
            {
                this.Value = value;
                this.LeftChildren = leftChildren;
                this.RightChildren = rightChildren;
            }

        public void Print (int indent = 0)
        {
            Console.Write(new string (' ', 2*indent));
            Console.WriteLine(this.Value);

            if (this.LeftChildren != null)
            {
                this.LeftChildren.Print(indent + 1);
            }
            if (this.RightChildren != null)
            {
                this.RightChildren.Print(indent + 1);
            }
        }
```

my class Node:

```
class Node 

  {
        private int data;
        private  Node left;
        private  Node right;

        public Node(int data = 0)
        {
            this.data = 0;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }
    }
```

So please I realy need to understand every connections so please if you can explain for me and help.

Comment: Please split the question. They are not related

Comment: Lowest common ancestor is a hard this to find. What is the expected run time?

Answer (score 0):

So here is my Binary tree code.

```
using System;

namespace MyBinaryTree
{
    // Creates a binary tree
    // Finds the lowest common ancestor in a binary tree

    class МainSolution
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Initialises binary tree view

            var btView = new ViewBinaryTree();
            btView.BinaryTreeView();

            // Initialises new binary tree

            BinarySearchTree tree = new BinarySearchTree();

            // Reads the desired number of nodes

            Console.Write("Enter how many nodes you want: ");
            int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Reads the nodes' values

            for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
            {
                Console.Write($"Enter name of {i} node: ");
                string nodeName = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();                
                tree.Insert(nodeName);                
            }

            // Lowest common ancestor - reads the two required values
            // Checks the values
            // Prints the lowest common ancestor

            bool isValid = true;

            while (isValid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Please enter the first node value: ");
                string nameOne = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                Console.Write("Please enter the second node value: ");
                string nameTwo = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

                if (tree.Find(nameOne) == true && tree.Find(nameTwo) == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    var result = tree.SearchLCA(tree.root, nameOne, nameTwo);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Lowest common ancestor: {result} ");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    isValid = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid name!");
                }
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Create a class Node:

```
// Creates the node structure

    class Node
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
        public Node RightChild { get; set; }
        public Node LeftChild { get; set; }

        public Node(string data, Node left = null, Node right = null)
        {
            this.Data = data;
            this.LeftChild = left;
            this.RightChild = right;
        }
    }
```

Here is my logic

```
 // Creates a binary tree.

    class BinarySearchTree
    {
        public Node root; // Creates a root node.

        public  BinarySearchTree() 
        {
            this.root = null;
        }

        // Adds a node in the binary tree.

        public void Insert(string inputValue)
        {
            Node newNode = new Node(inputValue); // Creates a new node.

            if (root == null) // If the tree is empty, inserts the new node as root
            {
                root = newNode;                
                return;
            }

            //Determins where to place the new node in the binary tree.

            Node current = root;
            Node parent = null;             

            while (true)
            {
                parent = current;
                if (inputValue.CompareTo(current.Data) < 0)
                {
                    current = current.LeftChild;
                    if (current == null)
                    {
                        parent.LeftChild = newNode;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    current = current.RightChild;
                    if (current == null)
                    {
                        parent.RightChild = newNode;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Checks if the node exists in the binary tree

        public bool Find(string inputValue)
        {
            Node current = root;
            while (current != null)
            {
                if (current.Data.Equals(inputValue))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (current.Data.CompareTo(inputValue) > 0)
                {
                    current = current.LeftChild;
                }
                else
                {
                    current = current.RightChild;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        // Creates a method to find the lowest common ancestor(LCA).

        public object SearchLCA(Node searchTree, string compareValue1, string compareValue2)
        {
            if (searchTree == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (searchTree.Data.CompareTo(compareValue1) > 0 && searchTree.Data.CompareTo(compareValue2) > 0)
            {
                return SearchLCA(searchTree.LeftChild, compareValue1, compareValue2);
            }
            if (searchTree.Data.CompareTo(compareValue1) < 0 && searchTree.Data.CompareTo(compareValue2) < 0)
            {
                return SearchLCA(searchTree.RightChild, compareValue1, compareValue2);
            }
            return searchTree.Data;
        }        
    }
```

"Thank you!"